# how to integrate facebook page on android application?

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, hyperlink, icons

I don't know how to add a link that goes to a page facebook on android application. 
I have already an image button that i want to be clickable and send the user to our facebook page.
thanks

Comment: when you click the button, open your browser and show the facebook page.

Answer (score 0):

Take WebView in your layout and try this

```
public void onClick(View v){
      String url = "www.facebook.com";
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```js
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);

 addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

 imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

 imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
      
         Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com"));
         startActivity(browserIntent);

  }

 });

}
 
}
```

Add this in XML Layout:

```html
  <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/android_button" />
```